# can any one help me on this android app

Tags: java, android

hello i have an app of POS ( point of sale ) 
i wanted to make it send printing data to be printed through bluetooth printer
i found this solution 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fidelier.posprinterdriver
its a driver for my printer 
they say

````
+### Print from your Android App (interactive user action)
+
+Create your ESC data using the helpers Create an Android Intent using Add your ESC data as a “Data” extra Start the intent.
+You can be printing in minutes with just a couple lines of code. It's as simple as creating your intent, adding your ESC formatted string and start the (service) intent.
+
+Example:
+
+```java
+
+String dataToPrint="$big$This is a printer test$intro$posprinterdriver.com$intro$$intro$$cut$$intro$";
+
+Intent intentPrint = new Intent();
+
+intentPrint.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
+intentPrint.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, dataToPrint);
+intentPrint.setType("text/plain");
+
+this.startActivity(intentPrint);
+
+```
````

can any body tell me how can i do that ???
where should i put these codes ? ?

Comment: You just need to send this explicit intent with the text in extra... so you insert this code where you yant to start the printing...

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have your activity with a button link to this method :

```
public void click(View v){
    Intent intentPrint = new Intent();

    intentPrint.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intentPrint.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Just some dummy text to print");
    intentPrint.setType("text/plain");

    this.startActivity(intentPrint);
}
```

By clicking on this button, the intent will be launched, this will probably open a list of application that can handle this kind of intent (ACTION_SEND), choose the correct one and this should do it.

Comment: http://decompile-storage.s3.amazonaws.com/complete/711989/967ed1f1805b1796c3f750cced8a98cb/source.zip

Comment: here is the source files

Comment: I can't read your source from my office. But you have everything to do it. If you want more help, you just need to ask... The intent just need to receive the text to print and the send the intent to start the activity... Update your question with the method from where you want to print at least.